# What does `async` mean in JavaScript when it is *not* followed by `function`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fastify

I stumble upon this code snippet while working on fastify.

```
module.exports = async function (fastify, opts) {
  fastify.register(proxy, {
    upstream: 'htt‌ps://news.ycombinator.com/',
    async preHandler(request, reply) {
      if (request.query.token !== 'abc') {
        throw fastify.httpErrors.unauthorized();
      }
    },
  });
};
```

Looks like it calls `fastify.register` with two parameters and the second parameter is an object. The first field is `upstream` but I don't get what comes next. What is this syntax after `async preHandler(request, reply)...`?

Comment: It's a method. `async` means it's an async method body, so it always returns a promise and enables the usage of `await`.

Comment: It's just a method. It's the same as `{ preHandler: async function(request, reply) { ... } }` - [Method definitions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

Comment: @VLAZ I'm looking at the ECMAScript grammar rules and the rules seem to require `async function` or `async $methodName` - I'm not seeing `async $functionName` as being permissable.

Comment: You're missing that `preHandler` is in an object. so is implicitly a function. `{async preHandler() {}}`

Comment: @Liam ahhhhh, clever

Comment: @Dai it's a shorthand method notation `{foo: function() {} }` == `{foo() {} }` it is *almost* the same. Shorthand methods cannot be called with `new` otherwise work the same as `function() {}`

Answer (score 2):

`fastify.register` seemingly has this signature: `fastify.register(proxy, {});`. So the second parameter is an **object**.

As [stated in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) and by [Andreas in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70168322/what-does-async-mean-in-javascript-when-it-is-not-followed-by-function/70168457#comment124038446_70168322) you can have an object that contains a method signature. So your object can be declared as:

```
{
   upstream: string,
   preHandler(request, reply){}
}
```

Where `preHandler(request, reply){}` is essentially a shorthand for `preHandler: function(request, reply){}`

You can then declare this method signature async (again as [stated in docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)). Which results in:

```
{
   async preHandler(request, reply){}
}
```

The above could also be declared as:

```
{
   preHandler: async function(request, reply){}
}
```